# Copy a mail using Microsoft Graph C# SDK

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I want to copy a mail from one folder to another.

Referring to the documentation, it should work like this:

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var destinationId = "destinationId-value";

await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"]
  .Copy(destinationId)
  .Request()
  .PostAsync();
```

However, when I try to use `.Copy()` like described I get the error, that I can't use it like a method. If I try to add the information as an `[]`, like it's done for the users or messages property, I receive a different error.

I have tried it like this:

```
var graphClient = GetGraphClientInstance();
var destinationFolderId = "destinationFolderId-value";

await graphClient.Users["myUserName"].Messages[specificMail.Id]
   .Copy(destinationFolderId )
   .Request()
   .PostAsync();
```

I'm using Microsoft.Graph version 5.0.0-preview-12.

Does anyone have an idea how to use the Copy property correctly?

Comment: I have used it the way the docs suggest and it work, does `.Move(destinationFolderId)` work for you?

Comment: @IvanGechev Nope, i get the same error. Can't be used like a method. I added the version of the Microsoft.Graph nuget to my original request. Maybe it's related to that.

Comment: both projects where I use `.Move()` and `.Copy()` have version `4.6.0` installed, maybe you can try downgrading.

Comment: @IvanGechev I can try this. However, in older versions the nuget is missing other functionalities i need :/.

Comment: what I used is `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.25.3" />` and after using `using Microsoft.Graph;` in my controller, the code snippet doesn't report error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPVha.png

Answer (score 1):

Using Microsoft.Graph v5 your original code:

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var destinationId = "destinationId-value";

await graphClient.Me.Messages["{message-id}"]
  .Copy(destinationId)
  .Request()
  .PostAsync();
```

should be changed to:

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var destinationId = "destinationId-value";

await graphClient.Users["myUserName"].Messages[specificMail.Id]
  .MicrosoftGraphCopy
  .PostAsync(new CopyPostRequestBody { DestinationId = destinationId });
```

5.1 has been released and the API changed a little:

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
var destinationId = "destinationId-value";

await graphClient.Users["myUserName"].Messages[specificMail.Id]
  .Copy
  .PostAsync(new CopyPostRequestBody { DestinationId = destinationId });
```

It looks like the C# doc is finally updated now that v5 is officially released, you can view it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-copy?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp).